# Failure to compile Storyboard in Xcode and it starts allocate all the RAM

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I am working on an app in XCode and it's getting bigger and bigger. For the last week I've been unable to compile the project.

When I click on 'run', the project gets stuck compiling file : "storyboard 1 of 1", and then starts allocating all the RAM. The whole machine stops responding because of this RAM problem.

Can anyone suggest what I might have been doing wrong?

Comment: Just how big is storyboard 1? Can you [edit] your post to add its code?

Comment: Storyboards don't exactly have code, just an xml representation. But if it lags his whole computer it must be huge. I'd suggest separating some views/controllers into separate `xib`/`storyboard` files.

Answer (score 1):

Quit xcode and Restart the system and try again worked for me.